# what does if any(j != " " for j in i): mean?

Tags: python

```
if any(j != " " for j in i):
```

what does this `izip_longest` mean

Also is there a site where they have definitions of all these?

Comment: Why do you have java AND python in your tags?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java.  Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: please clarify ,what you want to ask?

Comment: There is no `izip_longest` in your code example.

Comment: I just want to know what each individual thing means like what is the purpose of j, != , "  " , for j in i

Comment: The documentation for [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) is in the documentation. The documentation for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) is there too.

Answer (score 1):

*!=* means not equal

*for j in i* means loop through each element of i and put the result in j

so for example, if i is an list like this:

```
i=[" ", " ", " "]
```

then j != " " for j in i will check each item to see if it is not a " "

When put inside any() it will return true if any of the j values are not " ". So for the example for i above, the overall result will be false because all of the items inside i are " ".

If we instead set i to contain something else:

```
i==[" ", " ", "x"]
```

then

```
if any(j != " " for j in i):
```

will return True because it will find an element that is not a " " (one of them is "x")

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

1. (j != " " for j in i) returns generator with boolean elements (True, False)

Example:

```
i = ['a','b','c',' ', 'd']
gener = (j != " " for j in i)
print list(gener)
[True, True, True, False, True]
```

2. function any(): return True if any element of the list is True. If the list is empty, return False.

Examples:

```
print any([True,False,False])
True

print any([False,False,False])
False

print any([])
False
```

So, expression any(j != " " for j in i) return True if any element in list i !=" " and returns False if all elements in list i equals " " or i is empty